# SOAPUI - Insert a collection of objects in a single value field

Tags: soapui

How can I insert this collection of objects into a single value? (for a POST request)

```
"data": {
    "Idtest": 1,
    "Nametest": "test",
    "OBJECT" : {
                  "ID":1,
                   "NameTest": "BLA"
                }
  }
```

- The parameter is: OBJECT.
- And I want to insert in a value field this collection: {"ID":1,
  "NameTest": "BLA" }

Is this step possible in SOAPUI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615980/soapui-how-to-set-lists-as-property Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should help you, use a external source like CSV file in your [SoapUI script](http://www.soapui.org/data-driven-tests/functional-tests.html) and pass the required value as a variable from CSV file to your script, in this way what ever is there in your CSV file it will get passed as value in your script (i.e. in your script variable will be replaced with the value) during execution.

Refer this link for more details on [How to use external source in SoapUI](https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/)